# Django admin list display optimize queryset

Tags: python, django, optimization, admin, django-queryset

In `User` model i have a method:

```
@cached_property
    def income(self):
        return PartnerIncome.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('income'))['income__sum']*self.share_of_profit
```

PartnerIncome model:

```
class PartnerIncome(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    income = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

Now i want to show 'inccome' in `list_display=('income', )` at admin panel, but each object make extra query to database. How i can make `PartnerIncome.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('income'))` as a global variable for admin change list...

Comment: I have used raw sql at times when I had to do row level aggregated field. It was lot faster and the database usually caches that. One other technique you can do One other technique you can use is create another aggregate model that holds total income (and maybe other aggregated fields) and you update that field on PartnerIncome signals (you delete old income and add the new income)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about just overriding the `get_queryset` method in your `ModelAdmin`?

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('income', ...)

    def income(self, obj):
        return obj.income

    def get_queryset(self, request):
       queryset = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
       # you logic here to `annotate`the queryset with income
       return queryset
```

Documentation on `aggregation`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Without me really understanding your models and business logic.. here's a snippet from my own code as an example:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'books_count',)

    def books_count(self, obj):
        return obj.books_count

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(AuthorAdmin, self).get_queryset(
            request).annotate(books_count=Count('books'))
```